# Throw new Exception in asyc method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, methods, throw

How properly throw exception in async method?

```
public async void Method()
{
  if(value)
    throw new Exception("Error!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that, but return a `Task`. When you `await` the `Task`, it will throw the exception in the caller.

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    throw new Exception("Error!");
}

await DoSomethingAsync(); // throws
```

You almost never want to use `async void` as you will not be able to wait for it to complete, get a return value or have any exceptions thrown.